# Can I know all static routing routes?

Tags: next.js

I'd like to organize the components as below.

```
const Routes = ({routes}:{routes:Array<string>})=>{
  // expected: routes - ['apiTest', 'editor', 'pag', ...]
  const router = useRouter();

  return <>
    {
      routes.map((url, i)=>{
        return <Button onClick={()=>{ router.push(url) }} key={i}>{url}</Button>
      })
    }
  </>
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSruj.png)